# How to bind input field and update vuex state at same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Im coming from a React background and it's simply enough to set your state from a prop and you could call `setState({...})` to update the state, so, with vue / vuex, I find it difficult.

To simplify:

**Vuex State**

`name: "Foo bar"`

**Vuex Action**

`addName`

I can change the state no problem but I need to bind an input field and when change, the state is updated. Think of this as an update form where the user details are already pre-filled and they can change their name.

```
<input @change="addName(newName) v-model="newName" />
```

I could add a `watch` to watch for `newName` and update the state but, I need to pre-fill the input with the state. Ha! I could use `beforeMount()` but my state is not loaded as yet.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState([
  'name'
  ]),
},
beforeMount() {
  // this.newName = this.name
  console.log('Mounted') // Shows in console
  console.log(this.name) // nothing
}
```

Name shows in templete `<pre>{{ name }}</pre>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yo can use a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

```
computed:{
    name:{
        get: function(){ 
            return store.state.name; 
        }, 
        set: function(newName){ 
            store.dispatch('addName',newName); 
        }
    }
} 
enter code here
```

And set the `v-model` to the computed property `name` in  your `<input>` tag :

`<input v-model="name" />`

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/o14osotv/)

Comment: If my form has 4 or 10 inputs I'll have to do that for every single one?

Comment: @HelderLucas Yes. not fun. My approach is binding (v-model) them to an object in the data of your template, then send that object to a nicely named mutation and have the mutation alter the store. Alternative techniques are suggested here: https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2017/04/25/vuejs-two-way-data-binding-state-management-vuex-strict-mode/

Comment: How do you do if name is in an object ?

Comment: @HelderLucas, This blogpost mentions the vuex-map-fields library that should take care of the repetition (both getters&setters and mutations): https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/form-fields-two-way-data-binding-and-vuex/