# Vuejs Input Binding with Additional Properties in Computed Property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some data in my vuex store. I am loading that data in a computed property and based on some condition, I am adding some more data to the computed property's data. then I want to use this to populate a form. The form will have all properties including the newly added property. Now I want the user be able to change values in the form and submit it back to store. However, since everything is happening from Computed property, the user input changes don't reflect. Looking for help...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Vue Input Computed Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Vue Input Computed Example</h2>
    <!-- I want a form here which is filled with the film data. The idea is that user will update 
    the data and add data to the newly created properties and then submit form. -->
   <input type="text" v-model="item.a"/>
    <br /><br />
   <input type="text" v-model="item.b"/>
    <br /><br />
   <input type="text" v-model="item.c"/>
    <br /><br />
    from computed property 'film': {{film}}
    <br /><br />
    from data: {{item}}
  </div>
  <script>  
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: function() {
        return {
            item: {
                a:'',
                b:''
            }
        }
      },
      computed: {
        film () {
          var filmdata = {a:'1',b:'2'} // This actually comes from the Vuex store.
          // Next based on some condition, I want to add an additional property
          // I don't know how to send this to 'item' above. I don't want 'item' to have this additional 
          // property by default. Add it only if condition satisfies
          if (1 == 1) {
            filmdata.c = ''
          }
          return filmdata
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456784/7814783

Comment: @VamsiKrishna This actually works. However, the challenge is that when I add the new field filmdata.c = '', the change in value in the form still doesn't reflect. You can see the problem here. name.b doesn't update. https://jsfiddle.net/zhu53kfz/ Note that I don't want the original state to have the b property.

Comment: I cannot understand you properly .I don't see any `name.b` in the feudal

Comment: Can you see this updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ygfhaxow/2/ You will see that I am adding a new property data.b under get()

Comment: for the properties to be reactive you should set the properties before hand at the time of initialisationlike this https://jsfiddle.net/ygfhaxow/3/   see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Yes, this works if we set the property beforehand. However, what if I don't know the property initially and want it to be set dynamically? Vuejs talks about Vue.set, but I don't know how to use that. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up a condition to check if you want to add an extra property or not.

based on that condition commit a mutation which adds a new property to your stores state

```
if(condition){
    this.$store.commit('addPropertyToStore', {name: 'b', value:'xyz'});x
}
```

in your store add a mutation like this

```
mutationss:{
    addPropertyToStore(state, prop){
        Vue.set(state, prop.name, prop.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks so much, this is what I was looking for. Still one doubt. I should be setting this condition in my computed property's setter, right?

Comment: @asanas no in the created hook check whether the property is there or not

Comment: I am using Nuxt. My page works something like this: 1) Use the fetch method to fetch data from an api and add it to store. 2) Get this data from store into the page in a Computed Property. 3) Once the data is there in Computed property, only then I will be able to check for the property. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @asanas sry it's better you open in your question could not understand you completely and there are many moving parts

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Your solution is right. I think I just need to figure where to commit the mutation from. Thanks for helping!