# VueJs + Element-ui: how to get native event from input

Tags: vue.js, user-input, element-ui

I am trying to get the **event** from the **@input.native** attribute of a `el-input` tag.
Here the template code:

```
<el-input :value="filter.name" @input.native="updateFilter"></el-input>
```

And the script code:

```
updateFilter (e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

My **filter.name** has been initialized with value "aaa", then I type "b" in the field. For some reason, the output on the log is "aaa" but I need the "aaab" value instead.

Also I can't use **@input** because it return only the **value**, I need other attributes too.

Are there anyway to get the valid native input event?

**@Update: I am using Vuex so v-model is not an option**

Comment: This link might help  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Comment: Normally you can use v-model but if you want to pass events then above link might help

Comment: I didn't want to add a lot of detail but I am using Vuex here so v-model is not an option.

Comment: Have you gone through the above link which i mentioned which tells how to listen to events using native input?

Comment: I've tried the link and it not working at all, or should I say, it only return the **value** rather than the **event**. I quite sure that your solution definitely working with other UI framework, but this stupid element-ui is something else.

Comment: another way is try to use two variables use v-model to get the value and in the end add that to the "filter.name"(concatinating the strings) will it work?

Comment: you can use computed method also take one temp variable and make it to v-model. And assign new value to the variable in the vuex store(using computed setter and getter)            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456528/how-to-bind-input-field-and-update-vuex-state-at-same-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use computed method. Take one temporary variable and add that variable as v-model to your input. Whenever value is changing assign that variable to vuex store variable(nothing but string concatenation).  You can use setters and getters in computed.

Following link might help.

[assigning value to vuex store variable using computed setters and getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456528/how-to-bind-input-field-and-update-vuex-state-at-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

let's just do v-model with Vuex, and it is very simple :

```js
export default : {
...
computed : {
   filter : {
    get () { return this.$store.state.filter; };
    set (val) { this.$store.commit("setFilter", val);
  }
}
...
}
```

And then v-model onto filter will be magical.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing everything right. However, the value can't get updated unless you bind the model (using `v-model="filter.name"`) instead of doing `:value`.

Here is what I did:

#### HTML

```html
<el-input 
  class="small" 
  controls-position="right" 
  :value="someValue" 
  @input.native="someFunction">
</el-input>
```

#### Script

```html
<script>
    export default {
        name: "CustomizeSmtCampaign",
        data: function () {
            return {
                someValue: 'test'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            someFunction: function (val = '1') {
                console.log('Event Value', val.target.value, '  some value: ', this.blankValue);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### Output

This is the output I got on console as I typed

```
Event Value teste   some value:  test 
Event Value tester   some value:  test 
Event Value testere   some value:  test 
Event Value testerer   some value:  test 
Event Value testerere   some value:  test
```

---

So your code must be working.

**What is wrong, then?**

What's wrong is that you are binding to the `value`, not to the `model`.

When I changed the `:value="someValue"` to `v-model="someValue"`, the following was the output:

#### v-model Output

```
Event Value teste   some value:  teste 
Event Value tester   some value:  tester 
Event Value testere   some value:  testere 
Event Value testeree   some value:  testeree 
Event Value testereer   some value:  testereer 
Event Value testereere   some value:  testereere
```

---

#### Summary

Always bind the value using `v-model` (not using `:value`). That's how Vue achieves the reactiveness!

Hope that helped.

Comment: I am using Vuex here, so binding with `v-model` is not an option

Comment: why not? You can do 
`data: function () {
            return {
                someValue: this.$store.getters.someValue
            }
        }`
in the component you need the value.